# Automatically run down migration when deleting entire migration in Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-migration

Basically, If I'd want to delete an old migration, would I write a new migration which basically should be an inverse of the original one?

ie deleting what was inserted in up method, and then inserting the same in down method.

Or is there a way to automatically run the down methods, when deleting an entire migration file?

Ideally, what approach can I take to avoid any cleanup, manual work on the db etc.?

Comment: `bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --down FQCN`, but you'll have to instruct your team to run the command before deleting the migration. It'd better to revert the changes to the entities involved (that should be pretty easy with your version control system) and create a new migration with `maker`.

Comment: imo you wouldn´t delete "a migration" but update the entity-mappings accordingly and perform a doctrine:migrations:diff to have "a new migration" that would delete previous updates according to your model (in the simplest case)